# Stationary Time Series with Low Autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

I am starting to work with time series and am a bit lost with this specific time series.

I am working with the following time series. The Y variable is the total subscribers from a YouTube channel over time.

[image]

The first thing that I did was to perform the Dickey-Fuller test to see if the time series was stationary or not.

```
# Aplying Augmented Dickey-Fuller Contrast for Subscribers
sts.adfuller(ts['total_subscribers'])
```

There results were the following ones:

(-5.6570813525983965,
9.56618099517806e-07,
7,
654,
{'1%': -3.440388459298194,
'5%': -2.8659694611921034,
'10%': -2.569128861019929},
2366.473282410291)

Where the p-value is 9.56e-07. As 9.56e-07<0.05, we can refuse the null hypothesis (the series is NOT stationary) and conclude it is stationary.

I also created this plot to see how mean and variance were fluctuating over time, just to double-check:

[image]

Finally, I plot the ACF and PACF plots to see if it was possible to apply an AR model:

[image]

From the very first lag, the autocorrelation drops to around 0.30, which is pretty low. Something similar happens for the partial correlations:

[image]

I don't know if a stationary time series can have such a low correlation. Am I interpreting something wrong?

Of course, I tried to create an Autoregressive model with order 2, but I am not sure even the autocorrelation has a geometric decay...

This is what I get on the test data:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Stationarity means no distribution shift over time. Auto correlation being low or high is not an assumption for stationarity. By the way it's weird that the total subscribers has negative values!

Comment: Thanks. I see your point. It's normal it's negative. You can lose and gain subscribers. This is the compute of net subscribers gain by day (subscribers gain - subscribers lost). It's not a cumsum. Thanks.